# text box mouse out Javascript in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a text box and Button in MVC that by clicking the button controller action is called and other code in Jquery are also called. I wonder how can I replace this button with mouse out of the textbox. So all these action happen when user type something in text box and try to go to the next text box.

this is my MVC view code to create text box and Button:

```
Offer ID:
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ID, new { id = "ID" })

 <button id="btnSearch" data-url="@Url.Action("GetOffer", "LookUp")" class="btn btn-success search pull-left">Search</button>
```

this is the Jquery function that is call by clicking the button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {

    $("#btnSearch").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).data('url');

        getByOfferId(url);
    }
    );
});
```

I am not sure how specify this code in text box:

```
 data-url="@Url.Action("ActioName", "controllerName")"
```

and what action to call instead of this line:

```
    $("#btnSearch").click(function (evt) {
```

Comment: You don't want 'mouse out'. You need to handle the textbox `.change()` event - `$('#ID').change(function() { // your code });` And you can remove the `new { id = "ID" }` (its 'changing' the `id` attribute to exactly what it already is)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks what about this line data-url="@Url.Action("ActioName", "controllerName")"?

Comment: You can put that in the textbox - `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID, new { data_url = "Url.Action("ActionName", "controllerName")" })` and access it with `var url = $(this).data('url');` or simply just put it in the `.change()` function - `var url = '@Url.Action("ActionName", "controllerName")';`

Comment: @StephenMuecke great, it is working perfect thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `mouseout`, handle the `.change()` event of the textbox. You can add the url to the textbox using

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ID, new { data_url = "Url.Action("GetOffer", "LookUp")" })
```

Note the `id` attribute of the textbox will be `id="ID"` by default (generated by the html helper) so that you not need `new { id = "ID" }`. Then the script can be

```
$("#ID").change(function () {
    var url = $(this).data('url');
    getByOfferId(url);
}
```

alternatively you can just use (without the `data-url` attribute) assuming the script is not in a separate file.

```
$("#ID").change(function () {
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetOffer", "LookUp")';
    getByOfferId(url);
}
```